# Showing image, there is no error but image is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a C# project, and I am having a strange problem. I have an Image control and I am trying to display an image within it. There is no error or exception thrown, but the image doesn't display.

Below is the code I am using:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.UriSource = new Uri("images\\low_battery.png", UriKind.Relative);
imageIcon.Source = image;
imageIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

I have the directory image and the image file low_battery.png running in the same directory as  to where the executable is running from.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Is there actually an image at `images\\low_battery.png`?

Comment: Where are you putting the image? It won't show up unless you actually place it in a window.

Comment: Make sure the image is part of your project resources as well.

Comment: The imageIcon is a GUI component within the XAML of the WPF window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1) You can get the exception from WPF if you subscribe to the ImageFailed even on imageIcon and the and DownloadFailed event on BitmapImage.  Then put breakpoints in those methods and see what it says.

2) Before setting UriSource, call image.BeginInit().  After setting UriSource, call image.EndInit().  To help debug the problem, you can subscribe to the ImageFailed event on imageIcon and DownloadFailed on BitmapImage.  So the final code looks like this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri("/images/low_battery.png", UriKind.Relative);
image.DownloadFailed += image_DownloadFailed;
image.EndInit();

imageIcon.ImageFailed += imageIcon_ImageFailed;
imageIcon.Source = image;
imageIcon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

and further down:

```
void imageIcon_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Breakpoint here
}

void image_DownloadFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Breakpoint here
}
```

3) Another way to do this is to embed images directly into your project.  Do that by adding an images folder into your project, then adding the image, and setting the type to "Resource"

Comment: Thanks, I always get caught out by the begin and end init.

Comment: @Boardy And there is hardly ever a good reason to use it at all. Simply use the other BitmapImage constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Either call `image.BeginInit()` before setting `image.UriSource` and `image.EndInit()` afterwards, or simply use the BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri as argument:

```
var uri = new Uri("images\\low_battery.png", UriKind.Relative);
imageIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Comment: I like the constructor approach better than BeginInit() / EndInit().